# Зачем нужный пустые квадратные скобки в имени инпута

Tags: php, html

Всем привет возможно вопрос кому то покажется глупым т.к. занимаюсь программированием не долго . 
**Не знаю зачем нужный  пустые квадратные скобки в имени инпута **

пример html верстки:

```
<form action="GET.php" method="GET">
    <p>html<input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="html"></p>
    <p>css<input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="css"></p>
    <p>php<input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="php"></p>
    <p>javascript<input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="javascript"></p>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

пример php кода:

```
<?php
     if(isset($_REQUEST['lang']))
     {
      echo 'Вы знаете: ' . implode(',', $_REQUEST['lang']);
     }
?>
```

заранее спасибо

Comment: `print_r($_REQUEST['lang']);`

Comment: Это указание на то, что значения из этих инпутов обрабатываются как массив на серверной стороне.

Comment: А также http://docs.php.net/manual/ru/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это значит что на странице GET.php, где будет обработана отрпавка формы - ты получишь массив $_GET['lang'] с четырьмя элементами(если конечно их всех выбрать): ['html', 'css', 'php', 'javascript']

Например, чтобы получить значение 'css':

```
$element = $_GET['lang'][1];
```

Или пример обработки такого массива:

```
foreach($_GET['lang'] as $element) {
    echo $element . '<br />';
}
```

А если просто указать без скобок все четыре - тогда наверное получишь один элемент (даже если выбраны четыре) с последним значением(если не ошибаюсь)

Comment: Спасибо большое за развёрнутый ответ

Answer (score 0):

Если вы зададите без скобок то будут отправлены данные одного инпута(тот который был выбран последним), а если с скобками будет отправлен массив с данными инпутов.

Comment: нет *(12 символов нужно...)*

Comment: Отправляется всё независимо от скобок.